# Tabbar controller through UIButtons?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios4, uitabbarcontroller

I want to do application like tabbarController through UIButtons only and also i want to avoid 
using tabarController. how can I target viewController for every buttons which is in UIWindow?

Comment: Why don't you want to use a `UITabBarController` if you want to have the exact same functionality?

Comment: iwant to use color buttons, if we subclass UItababrcontroller,it will be rejected.so i need same functionality for UIbuttons..is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://blog.theanalogguy.be/2010/10/06/custom-colored-uitabbar-icons/)'s a link which shows you how to add coloured icons to the `UITabBarController`, and it seems as though there are multiple ways of doing this online. Try searching for "uitabbarcontroller color icons" on your favourite search engine, and hopefully you'll find more information on how to do this.

If you really have your heart set on implementing your own `UITabBarController`, I would suggest making 1 super view which has the buttons on the bottom, and on each button press, load a new subview above them to make it look like it's a `UITabBarController`.

Hope that Helps!

Comment: How about if we want to use custom images in the UITabBarController, like we use in UIButtons? I don't think it is possible using UITabBarController. But is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Have a set of buttons in a scrollview (if the number of buttons exceeds the frame) and set each button an action to present the modal view ?